Why do I get this error in gforth random number generotor random.fs?
I’m trying this word shuffle:
: random-range ( n -- r )
  dup 1- random mod
;

: shuffle ( array len -- )
    1- 0 do
        i random-range swap rot over !
    loop ;

but gforth is giving this error:
~/gforth/random.fs:34: Undefined word
    user rng-state $10 >>>cell-<<< uallot drop
Backtrace:
$107349A20 throw 
$10735FCC0 no.extensions 
$107349CE0 interpreter-notfound1

This is line 34 in random.fs extension that I took from here
cell is listed as a word in index of words
So, I’don’t understand why I’m getting this error? Can you help?
EDIT
When I do see cell I get this:
see cell 
8 Constant cell  
 ok

Is this right?


~/gforth/random.fs:34: Undefined word
    user rng-state $10 >>>cell-<<< uallot drop


The error about cell- (not cell — they are different words). The message means that the word cell- is not found. Probably, you are using an outdated version of Gforth.
Try to define cell- before including random.fs as:
: cell- ( n -- n )  1 cells - ;


Your random-range is incorrect, it sometimes results in division by zero.
shuffle is also incorrect. Try to write stack comment after each command like this:
: shuffle ( array len -- )
    1- 0 ( array len-1 0 )
    \ NB: it loops almost forever if len=1
    do ( array )
        i random-range ( array rnd )
        swap ( rnd array )
        rot ( rnd array x ) \ stack underflow
        over ! ( rnd ) \ It tries to write array at unknown address
    loop ;


Thanks. random.fs had a word hashkey2 that gave an error. I figured that this word would be in hash.fs in the gforth library. It was. But this time I got  an error for the word third occurring in hash.fs. The word third seems to be in gforth since version 1.0. How can this word give an error? I changed third to rot rot and this time I got another error with another word. So I'm curious to know what's wrong with my installation. It is version 0.7.3. I installed it with MacPorts and also with Homebrew. Both installed the same version. What do you suggest I do?

@zeynel, you are using a library, source files and manual from the current Gforth version, but the binary is from the very old version. I suggest to download and build the bleeding edge snapshot (see the manual), or use a docker image.  Otherwise, use the files and manual from the old 0.7.3 release tarball.

Thank you very much. I couldn't make the install from Github or tarball work. I asked a question at Superuser but there was no answer https://superuser.com/questions/1851273/how-can-i-fix-the-frozen-terminal-during-installation But I was able to make the Docker work. So now I'm up to date.  The only thing is that Docker desktop needs to run for gforth to work. I will continue to try to install it from Github or tarball. Many thanks again.

Unfortunately, Docker did work for me either. It heats up my old MacBook Air badly.

__atomic_compare_exchange_n(a_addr, &uprev, unew, 0,  __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
Do you know what this line (line 3392) does in this file https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/prim
This is the line that breaks the installation.

__atomic_compare_exchange is not the problem root.
I can only suggest to use another Forth system for a while. For example, VfxForth. Of course, it's impossible to use Gforth-specific libraries in other Forth systems without a compatibility layer. Standard Forth programs can be used in any standard Forth system with sufficient capabilities.

I gave up on installing the new version. I'll continue with the old version that I have. I think that would be good for learning purposes for me now.
